# Content beneath absolute positioned CSS3 Tab Bar

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a tab bar made with CSS3 only (and I really want to avoid any javascript/jquery). I found a nice tutorial and modified the source code for my needs. Unfortunately any content beneath my tab bar will be placed in the background of the "tab-content"-ids since they are positioned in absolute mode. But I want e.g. the footer to appear beneath my tab-bar-content with variable height and not behind it. I already tried to change the positioning parameters but as a result the "tab-content" will flow under the single tab1/2/3/4-labels.

Here is my **style sheet**:

```
    .tabs input[type=radio] {
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
    left: -9999px;
}
.tabs {
    width: 960px;
    float: none;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top:30px;
    font-size:14px;
}
.tabs li {
    float: left;
}
.tabs label {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    color: #aaa;
}
.tabs label:hover {
    top: 0;
    color: #000;
}
[id^=tab]:checked + label {
    color: #000;
}
[id^=tab]:checked ~ [id^=tab-content], [id^=tab]:checked ~ [id^=tab-content] > div {
    display: block;
}
.tab-content {
    z-index: 2;
    display: none;
    text-align: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 140%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 53px;
    left: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size:14px;
    float:left;
}
.tab-content > div {
    display: none;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    animation-duration: 0.5s;
}
.TabBar {
    float:left;
    width: 960px;
    height:auto;
}
```

and my **HTML** source code:

```
<!-- TABBAR !-->
  <div class="TabBar">
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li>
        <input type="radio" checked name="tabs" id="tab1">
        <label for="tab1">First Tab</label>
        <div id="tab-content1" class="tab-content">
          <div class="animated  fadeInRight"> Lorem Ipsum 1 </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2">
        <label for="tab2">Second Tab</label>
        <div id="tab-content2" class="tab-content">
          <div class="animated  fadeInRight"> Lorem Ipsum 2 </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab3">
        <label for="tab3">Third Tab</label>
        <div id="tab-content3" class="tab-content">
          <div class="animated  fadeInRight "> Lorem Ipsum 3 </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab4">
        <label for="tab4">Fourth Tab</label>
        <div id="tab-content4" class="tab-content">
          <div class="animated  fadeInRight "> Lorem Ipsum 4 </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

And here an example of my issue on CodePen: http://codepen.io/DanielCoding/pen/Fxrnw

I don't have an idea how I could handle this.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: hi, sorry. I want the following content to appear under my tab bar. not behind it. I already edited my first post.

Comment: I tried using your code and it looks like the content is under the tab bar. http://codepen.io/skimberk1/pen/9250db16d142df220a664a2e38a6bcab

Comment: Thank you. But my issue are the containers beneath the whole tab bar thing. If i want to place a footer under the tab bar the content of the footer will appear under the clickable tab-pads in the same position like the lorem ipsum content since this lorem ipsum content is placed absolutely. Here is a example on codepen: http://codepen.io/DanielCoding/pen/Fxrnw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand this problem, you have to change some properites in you css.

1. .tab-content set whitout position propiretes(only float:left;) and set margin-top: 35px;
2. .tabs label set position: absolute and set left properites for ever label separetly like .tabs label:nth-child(1){left:0px} .tabs label:nth-child(2){left:100px} .tabs label:nth-child(3){left:200px}

Now you can add div footer in the end of page.

I hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

I have modified your css. It works fine now.

```
.wrapper .TabBar {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
}
.wrapper .TabBar ul {
  padding: 0;
}
.wrapper .TabBar ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
.wrapper .TabBar ul li input[type=radio] {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.wrapper .TabBar ul li input[type=radio]:checked ~ .tab-content {
  display: block;
}
.wrapper .TabBar ul li input[type=radio]:checked + label {
  background-color: #00c9ed;
}
.wrapper .TabBar ul li input[type=radio]:hover + label {
  background-color: #8eeeff;
}
.wrapper .TabBar ul li label {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
}
.wrapper .TabBar ul li label:hover {
  background-color: #8eeeff;
}
.wrapper .TabBar ul li .tab-content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

You need to apply your animations.

Comment: I have done this without modifying your markup. You can make it more efficient. I have created a tabbed view. You may look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202160/tabbed-navigation/19203212#19203212

Comment: I have done it in two ways. But the one using :target selector is very powerful.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the issue right then you just need to add some css to force the tabs container to wrap around the floated elements and occupy the height of the elements.

Just add

```
.tabs {
  overflow:hidden;
  ...
```

I hope this helps.