# Unable to highlight the first element of a menu list

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a List of menu as below:

```
<ul id="tablist">
    <li><a class="tab" href="#" onclick="return expandcontent('sc1', this)">Menu1</a></li>
    <li><a class="tab" href="#" onclick="return expandcontent('sc2', this)">Menu2</a></li>
    <li><a class="tab" href="#" onclick="return expandcontent('sc3', this)">Menu3</a></li>
    <li><a class="tab" href="#" onclick="return expandcontent('sc4', this)">Menu4</a></li>
    <li><a class="tab" href="#" onclick="return expandcontent('sc5', this)">Menu5</a></li>
</ul>
```

On click the menu item it will show div sc1,sc2,sc3,sc4,sc5 resp. The javascript I have used is below:

```
var initialtab=[1, "sc1"]

function cascadedstyle(el, cssproperty, csspropertyNS) {
    if (el.currentStyle)
        return el.currentStyle[cssproperty]
    else if (window.getComputedStyle) {
        var elstyle=window.getComputedStyle(el, "")
        return elstyle.getPropertyValue(csspropertyNS)
    }
}

var previoustab=""

function expandcontent(cid, aobject) {
    var links=document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(i=0;i<links.length;i++) {
        if(links[i].className=="tab") {
            links[i].style.fontWeight="normal";
        }
    }
    aobject.style.fontWeight="bold";
    if (document.getElementById) {
        highlighttab(aobject)
        detectSourceindex(aobject)
        if (previoustab!="")
            document.getElementById(previoustab).style.display="none"
        document.getElementById(cid).style.display="block"
        previoustab=cid
        if (aobject.blur)
            aobject.blur()
        return false
    } else
        return true
}

function highlighttab(aobject) {
    if (typeof tabobjlinks=="undefined")
        collecttablinks()
}

function collecttablinks() {
    var tabobj=document.getElementById("tablist")
    tabobjlinks=tabobj.getElementsByTagName("A")
}

function detectSourceindex(aobject) {
    for (i=0; i<tabobjlinks.length; i++) {
        if (aobject==tabobjlinks[i]) {
            tabsourceindex=i 
        }
    }
}

function do_onload() {
    var cookiename=(typeof persisttype!="undefined" && persisttype=="sitewide")? "tabcontent" : window.location.pathname
    var cookiecheck=window.get_cookie && get_cookie(cookiename).indexOf("|")!=-1
    collecttablinks()
    initTabcolor=cascadedstyle(tabobjlinks[1], "fontWeight", "fontWeight")
    initTabpostcolor=cascadedstyle(tabobjlinks[0], "fontWeight", "fontWeight")
    if (typeof enablepersistence!="undefined" && enablepersistence && cookiecheck) {
        var cookieparse=get_cookie(cookiename).split("|")
        var whichtab=cookieparse[0]
        var tabcontentid=cookieparse[1]
        expandcontent(tabcontentid, tabobjlinks[whichtab])
    } else
        expandcontent(initialtab[1], tabobjlinks[initialtab[0]-1])
}

if (window.addEventListener)
    window.addEventListener("load", do_onload, false)
else if (window.attachEvent)
    window.attachEvent("onload", do_onload)
else if (document.getElementById)
    window.onload=do_onload
</script>
```

The divs are as follows:

```
<div id="tabcontentcontainer">
<div id="sc1" class="tabcontent">
<span style="font-size:9pt; color:black;">Content 1 goes here</span>
</div>
<div id="sc2" class="tabcontent">
<img src="images/image.png"/>
</div>
<div id="sc3" class="tabcontent">
<span style="font-size:9pt; color:black;">Content 3 goes here</span>
</div>
<div id="sc4" class="tabcontent">
<span style="font-size:9pt; color:black;">Content 4 goes here</span>
</div>
<div id="sc5" class="tabcontent">
<span style="font-size:9pt; color:black;">Content 5 goes here</span>
</div>
```

My problem is I am unable to highlight the first menuitem as bold when the page loads i.e. the I want to highlight Menu1 as default selected item when the page loads. Please help out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't have used javascript for this menu. This whole menu can easily be done using css

Comment: @ArunAravind how would you animate those menu items and make them bold on click via CSS?

Comment: Using pure css, either you could use a hidden radio button, and :checked selector.

Comment: Or even you can use :focus selector, but its a bit jerky

Comment: I have already posted it on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202160/tabbed-navigation/19202864#19202864

Comment: And there is another way too. using :target selector. I have done it in both ways on the above mentioned link. It is simple, elegant, and bug free. with a little bit of javascript you could make it more interesting.

Answer (score 2):

using CSS

```
#tablist li:first-child {
   background-color: #0094ff;
}
```

Comment: He wants to select the first list element. Not the first ul.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want to use:

```
ul li:first-child {
   font-weight:bold;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yn7pG/1/)**

Comment: You have to save your fiddle before copying the link, your link points to an empty fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this is quite easy and the JS error would certainly come up if you checked your [console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console). You're missing IDs of your LI elements, so you can't make the first LI bold by using `getElementById()`.

Here's an updated HTML code that will work:

```
<ul id="tablist">
<li><a class="tab" id="sc1" href="#" onclick="return expandcontent('sc1', this)">Menu1</a></li>
<li><a class="tab" id="sc2" href="#" onclick="return expandcontent('sc2', this)">Menu2</a></li>
<li><a class="tab" id="sc3" href="#" onclick="return expandcontent('sc3', this)">Menu3</a></li>
<li><a class="tab" id="sc4" href="#" onclick="return expandcontent('sc4', this)">Menu4</a></li>
<li><a class="tab" id="sc5" href="#" onclick="return expandcontent('sc5', this)">Menu5</a></li>
</ul>
```

A working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TSHVP/

Depending on which browsers you're targetting, you might even go with a CSS selector, which would be quicker than using JavaScript on window load (see other answers).

Comment: The IDs are not for the menus but for the divs which I am going to toggle onclick the menu.

Comment: ah, I see... maybe it would be good to update your HTML to have a full working HTML code (including those DIVs)? I might be able to update my answer then

Comment: once again, we're missing a `get_cookie` function definition, so the example code won't work how you'd like it to... do you have a *get_cookie()* function in your code somewhere?

Comment: There is no get_cookie function in my code but the code works fine as far as toggling of the DIVs is concerned.

Comment: this is a bit confusing now, as your code is relying on cookies being stored and retrieved on the client side, so when you reload the page, the DIV which was selected last would become active... if that's not the desired functionality, then a part of your code is redundant and should be removed... so do you ALWAYS want first item to be selected when you reload the page?

Answer (score 1):

If you allowed to use JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tablist>li').first().css( "font-weight", "bold" );
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to achieve this,

```
$("#tablist li:first").css('font-weight','bold');
```

[Check Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/smanimani/nZCFF/1/)

I am using jquery version1.9.1

Comment: please mention jQuery if you're using it for an answer, as the OP did not initially mention it (meaning they might not be familiar with it at all)

Comment: If I use this, my divs doesn't show up at all. I think it's not just making the item bold but solving some conflict with the js I am using for toggling the divs.

Comment: @user1126060 : you want to highlight the first menu item is bold while page loading, right?

Comment: Do you using any third party plugin for menu control ? If yes, can you send me the link,,